# Constructing an entire function of order $\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, entire-functions

The definition of order I'm using is the following:

An entire function $f$ is said to be of finite order if there is a number $t > 0$ such that $$|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|^{t}}$$

for all sufficiently large $z$. The infimum of all such $t$ is called the order of $f$.

In another problem I had to prove that $cos(z^{\frac{1}{2}})$ was of order $\frac{1}{2}$. So, for this problem I'm wondering whether it would be possible to show that $cos(z^{\frac{1}{4}})$ was of order $\frac{1}{4}$.

From Taylor Series expansions:

$$ |cos(z^{\frac{1}{4}})|= |\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=0} (-1)^n  \frac{z^{\frac{n}{4}}}{(2n)!} |$$

$$ e^{|z|^{\frac{1}{4}}} = \Sigma^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{|z|^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n!}   $$

So, $|cos(z^{\frac{1}{4}})| \leq e^{|z|^{\frac{1}{4}}}  $ for sufficiently large $z$.

But,

$$ cos(z^{\frac{1}{4}} ) = \frac{e^{\frac{x}{4}}+ e^{\frac{-x}{4}} }{2} \geq \frac{e^{\frac{x}{4}}}{2} = \frac{e^{|z|^{\frac{1}{4}}}}{2}  $$

Hence, $\frac{1}{4}$ is the infimum and the order of the function is $\frac{1}{4}$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Note that $f(z)=\cos{z^{1/4}}$ isn’t an entire function: what is the vanishing order of $1-f(z)$ at $z=0$?

Comment: Is $\cos(z^{1/4})$ entire?  You may want to check the terms in the Taylor series closely.  And then try $\cos(z^{1/4})+\cosh(z^{1/4})$.

Comment: I don't think you write down the Taylor expansions for $\cos(z)$ and $\exp(z)$ correctly.

Comment: @OscarLanzi It seems you are correct. Do I show that $cos(z^{\frac{1}{4}}) +cosh(z^{\frac{1}{4}}) $ is of order $0.25$ using Taylor series expansions?

Comment: Yes show that $\sum_{k=0}^3 e^{i^k z^{1/4}}$ is entire.

Comment: Even easier show that $\sum \frac{z^{n}}{(4n)!}$ works